# Error using CHCSV Parser: No known class method for selector 'arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:encoding:error:'

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, csv

I'm using CHCSV Parser to create an array using a csv. However, I'm getting this error:

> No known class method for selector 'arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:encoding:error:'

This is how I create my array:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"csv"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (rows == nil) {
    //something went wrong; log the error and exit
    NSLog(@"error parsing file: %@", error);
    return; 
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The header from github](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser/blob/master/CHCSVParser/CHCSVParser.h) appears to have no such method.  Your choices appear to be:

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath;
+ (instancetype)arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath options:(CHCSVParserOptions)options;
```

Note that neither has an `encoding:` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included CHCSVParser.h? It declares arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile methods to extend NSArray.

Comment: Thanks, yeah. I already added CHCSVParser.h.