# CHCSV Parser error: No known class method for selector 'arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:encoding:error:'

Tags: ios, objective-c

When attempting to use the CHCSV parser like this:

```
#import "CHCSVParser.h"
....

- (IBAction)hi:(id)sender {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nood" ofType:@"csv"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    if (rows == nil) {
        //something went wrong; log the error and exit
        NSLog(@"error parsing file: %@", error);
        return;
    }

}
```

I get the error:

> No known class method for selector arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:encoding:error:

I have included the CHCSV header but this error still happens.
This question is the exact same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951333/error-using-chcsv-parser-no-known-class-method-for-selector-arraywithcontentso) one but it never got answered so please don't mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: [How to bump a question thats the same as the one you wanted to ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471)

Comment: Sorry I missed that next time I will do what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The header from github](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser/blob/master/CHCSVParser/CHCSVParser.h) appears to have no such method.  Your choices appear to be:

```
+ (instancetype)arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath;
+ (instancetype)arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:(NSString *)csvFilePath options:(CHCSVParserOptions)options;
```

Note that neither has an `encoding:` argument.

Comment: Thank you it worked. This is the new correct line "NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:csvFilePath];"

Comment: +1 yep. I rewrote the parser a while ago and trimmed down the convenience methods.  This one was one of the casualties.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is asked long back but still i will add

These methods has been deprecated which Dev has already rewritten in .h file.

Instead you have to use

```
- (IBAction)hi:(id)sender {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nood" ofType:@"csv"];


NSArray *rows = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] options:options];
if (rows == nil) {
    //something went wrong; log the error and exit
    NSLog(@"error parsing file: %@", error);
    return;
}
```

}